# How to disable Datagridview1_cellvalidating temporarily in vb.net when querying data from mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I have Problem here in DataGridView1_CellValidating. Everytime I fire the search button and the data place in designated rows it pop ups my messagebox three times. why i use a cell validating in that datagridview because I use it for inserting my data to the database, and I want to use that datagridview also to display datas everytime I Search. Is it possible to disable temporarily the datagridview_cellvalidating when I fire Search Button? then enable again so that I could use it again for the user's input. Here is my Codes in DataGridView1_CellValidating:

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue) Then
        ' Show the user a message
        MessageBox.Show("You have left the cell empty")
        ' Fail validation (prevent them from leaving the cell)
        e.Cancel = False
    End If
```

This is for my Search Button

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = ("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=12345;database=dbsis3bkenth;")
        Try
            conn.Open()

        sql = "SELECT LName,FName,MI FROM tblsisterbrother where IDNoBrodSis = '" & cbIDNo.Text & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()

        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Found.!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Record Unfound.!")
        End If
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error in searching to database:error is:" & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    dr.Close()
    Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = cmd
    DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "tblsisterbrother")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "tblsisterbrother"
    conn.Dispose()
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Please Help me and suggest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would remove the subscribed event then re-subscribe when done your work

```
RemoveHandler DataGridView1.CellValidating, AddressOf DataGridView1_CellValidating
' do work
AddHandler DataGridView1.CellValidating, AddressOf DataGridView1_CellValidating
```